# How to get the part of text from some element via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the text inside first li :

```
<li data-type="course" value="1">
   This Is Some Course
   <ul class="submenu-widget" style="">
      <li data-type="section" value="3">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="4">&nbsp;- This Is Another Section
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="5">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="8">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="9">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="10">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="11">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="12">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
      <li data-type="section" value="13">&nbsp;- This Is Some Section - Copy
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I tried :

```
var course_name = ui.item.parent().parent().text();
```

But it returns the text of all the sections also..but I want this to return "This Is Some Course".

Comment: `$.trim(ui.item.closest('ul').find('li:first').text());`

Comment: What does `ui.item` refer to?

Comment: thanks for quick response tushar .. this code returns "This Is Some Section" while i want this to return "This Is Some Course"

Comment: The `value` attribute isn't valid on `li` elements.

Comment: ui.item refers to the <li data-type="course" value="1">

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/37/)**

You could use `:first` selector :

```
$('.submenu-widget li:first').text();
```

If you want to get the li outside th ul you could select it using data attribute :

```
$("li[data-type='course']").text();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply zakaria , i want to return This Is Some Course, it would return this is some section

Comment: is there something like this  in jquery ... ui.item.closest("li[data-type='course']").text();

Comment: _ui.item refers to the <li data-type="course" value="1">_ so you could try `ui.item.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the text "This Is Some Course" use:

```
$.trim( $('li[data-type="course"]').clone().children().remove().end().text() )
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/o90aL5Lx/)**

Comment: thats good..but there may be many elements with li[data-type="course"] i want to get the current value only.. 
ui.item refers to the <li data-type="course" value="1">

Comment: Without code showing how you arrive at ui.item we can't create a selector.

Answer (score -1):

If you use this:

```
$("li[data-type='course']").text();
```

You will get the text of the input field which contain "This is some Course"

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
jQuery("body>ul>li").contents()
  .filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text()
```